# Load orchard custom widget asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I have written custom module using some examples. I'm using ContentPartDriver inherited class to render results...

for example:

```
        protected override DriverResult Display(ContentPickerPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper) {
        string IWSUrl = IWSUrlRuleProvider.BuildIWSUrl(part);
        var lstTypeItems = _contentpicker.GetItems(IWSUrl);

        return ContentShape("Parts_ContentPicker", () => shapeHelper.Parts_ContentPicker(
                    Items: (lstTypeItems as List<Item>)));
    }
```

Module is requesting web service to get some information... As there is a lot info it takes about 400ms to just call web service...
I have about 10 same modules per page and it takes 400*10 secs to render...

How can i render this module asynchronously in orchard cms?(So page will be rendered and after there will be ajax calls for each modules)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can either just create a controller and make an ajax call after the page loads from your parts view to the controller which will in turn call your service, or you could try using the ajaxify widget, which will only load your widget after the page has loaded, but I have never actually tried it :) [Ajaxify](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.IDeliverable.AjaxWidget)

Answer (score 2):

You may use this module in order to make your widgets async load:

http://orchardmarket.net/Catalog/Modules/ideliverable-widgets

http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.IDeliverable.AjaxWidget

We have used it in 1.7.x Orchard sites and worked smoothly.